# How to make sure that tiles are fully rendered in using google map api

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3, openlayers

I am able to capture the google map image. But I want it to capture automatically. I am able to but it has image which is not fully rendered. So I want to know is there any proper way to know that required tiles are loaded and rendered fully.I tried tilesloaded, idle events but seems not working rightly.
is it a good way to use idle under tilesloaded...i may sound wrong as i'm very new to google map api.

```
function initialize() {
  var mapOptions = {
    zoom: 17,
    center: new google.maps.LatLng(lat,lng),
    mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP,
    rotateControl:true
  };
  map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map_canvas'),  mapOptions);
  google.maps.event.addListener(map, 'tilesloaded', function(event) {
      console.log("tilesloaded");
      map.addListener('idle', function(event) { 
        console.log("idle");
    });  
  });
}  
google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can easily add a listener on the `tilesloaded` event. Like this:

```
google.maps.event.addListener(map, 'tilesloaded', function() {
   ..... your code ...
});
```

Comment: is it a good way to use idle under tilesloaded...i may sound wrong as i'm very new to google map api as i put code snippet in my ans sec.

Comment: I think you should use only tilesloaded listner without idel. the tilesloaded even is rise when all the visible tiels are rendered...

Comment: And if you find my answer useful you should mark as accepetd and rate it correctly. not only add obviuos code and post like is your

Comment: Normally when you want show the code is better edit the question and add the code instead of post an answer. In this way you question is rated

Comment: I have the problem that the tilesloaded event fires even when the map is still grey and not rendered yet... Works not for me how it should.

Comment: Is strange ..normally work right .. post a proper question and add the code  .. you are use.. ( a minimal code)  ..